# There is an [all] tag that needs to be removed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

I've just found the [all](/questions/tagged/all) tag. I suspect it has been created when people try to enter things like [catch-all](/questions/tagged/catch-all) as "catch all" rather than "catch-all".

We can't just delete this tag, but need people to go though the questions retagging as appropriate.

Comment: Apologies for the +1, I know you don't want any more rep ;)

Comment: @Lix - Touché. I suspend that rule when asking questions. It's only fair people have the opportunity to take rep off me when I'm asking questions.

Comment: 42.5K minus 2... "fair"? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag definitely can't stand on it's own.  I've added it to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012

If it is indeed [catch-all](/questions/tagged/catch-all) then the question should be retagged as such (with the [catch](/questions/tagged/catch) removed).

---

This tag has been removed from the system.

Comment: Wow.  How'd that happen?

Comment: @AdamRackis Well, you retired after your victory, but the work continues...

Comment: Think of me more as Professor Emeritus ;)

Comment: @AdamRackis PROFESSOR?!?!  Oh no.  Do **not** make me do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1h8M.gif)

Comment: Oh, now that's just awesome.

Comment: Causing more trouble, eh :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/why-was-my-answer-deleted-and-turned-into-a-comment

Comment: @AdamRackis Indeed.  Some people apparently is all wound up because their rep-whoring one-liner was axed.  Oh well, the world still turns...

Comment: @AdamRackis Hey, have you seen [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012#comment359360_128315).  Look at all that self-generating meta rep =)