# Presumably wrong answer deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This answer was deleted even though it answered the question:

> Are you inserting the value null, or a zero length string ''?
>
> A zero length string will be accepted with a NOT NULL constraint as it
>   isn't null. If not can you please post your insert code too?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218308/50552

A very similiar answer was posted later and got accepted as the answer.

The post was from a 30 rep user who is presumably new, and was deleted by a moderator, that is, without any voting.

What's up?

Comment: [OMG its teh moderatorz again!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/why-was-my-answer-deleted-and-turned-into-a-comment)

Answer (score 12):

> deleted by owner 15 mins ago

Self deleted, but probably in response this comment:

> Are you asking questions, or posting an answer?

If the user wasn't 100% confident in the answer I can understand why they'd delete it, especially if the post had been deleted (and restored) by a moderator - as can be seen from the [revisions history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10218308/revisions)

As to how the moderator came across the answer there are several mechanisms:

1. They could have seen it as part of their regular browsing of the site.
2. They could have seen it from the "review" pages.
3. There could have been a flag raised by another user.
4. The automated "low quality" flag could have been raised on the answer.

Comment: As a little nugget of info, the revisions show that it was earlier deleted by a moderator, then undeleted a few minutes later - but this was before the self-initiated deletion: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10218308/revisions

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Ah missed that.

Comment: This just restates the facts?  The question is how was the moderator's attention directed to this answer, is the mod correct in deciding to delete it, and if not, does this happen often enough to warrant a change in process (and I'd argue that it does.)

Comment: @Andomar - I'm not sure I follow your reasoning here, but I'll try and update the answer.